# Packet routing from docker container to host ip

Tags: networking, ip, routing, tcp-ip

I am wondering what is tbe route for a packet sent from src being the docker container with its own 'dockerised' IP, to the IP address of the VM, on which this docker process runs? Will the packets ever leave the VM or would they be routed locally?

This is analogous to having a server side process listening on all interfaces and port XXX, and the client sending packets to host_ip:XXX

Answer (score 0):

> Will the packets ever leave the VM or would they be routed locally?

I am not sure if I understand the question. The "VM" is a bunch of namespaces, including a network namespace. The docker host uses the main network namespace. If a container sends a packet, then this packet lives in the network namespace of the container, and to be processed in the main network namespace of the host, it **has** to leave this container eventually. And yes, this happens "locally", on the physical machine that contains all those namespaces.

Actually, the process is fairly involved: There's tons of iptables-rules both in the main network namespace, and in the container network namespace (just go and inspect them on your docker installation).

Answer (score 0):

These packets are routed locally over the default Docker bridge network.

For example, on a CentOS 8 host with Docker CE's `docker0` default bridge network setup:

```
on-the-host$ ip a sh
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:b4:8e:4b:9d:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.8.151/24 brd 172.20.8.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 3175sec preferred_lft 3175sec
102: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:cd:4e:e9:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.200.0.1/24 brd 10.200.0.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now, from within a Docker container, let's try to reach the host instance:

```
within-docker-container$ ip a eth0
212: eth0@if213: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:0a:c9:08:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.201.8.9/24 brd 10.201.8.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

within-docker-container$ traceroute -Un 172.20.8.151
traceroute to 172.20.8.151 (172.20.8.151), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.20.8.151  0.054 ms  0.010 ms  0.010 ms
```

You can see the packet arrives directly at the host's `eth0` NIC.

But bear in mind that a lot of low-level action goes on the host instance. `iptables` rules, network namespaces etc.!